Is this correct? trying to find the Complex Fourier series of $e^x$
I'm trying to do so but when calculating for the coefficients I get ugly expressions, wanted to check if I might be missing something:
this is what I did initially:
$$c_{n} =\frac{1}{2\pi}{\displaystyle \intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}}f\left(x\right)e^{-inx}dx
 =\frac{1}{2\pi}{\displaystyle \intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}}e^{x}e^{-inx}dx
 =\frac{1}{2\pi}{\displaystyle \intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}}e^{x\left(1-in\right)}dx
 =\frac{1}{2\pi}\left.\frac{e^{x\left(1-in\right)}}{1-in}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}
 =\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{e^{\pi\left(1-in\right)}}{1-in}-\frac{e^{-\pi\left(1-in\right)}}{1-in}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi\left(1-in\right)}\left[{i\sin\left(\pi\left(1-in\right)\right)}\right]$$
but here since I have no meaning for $\sin{(\pi-in)}$ I instead decided to expand it with the exponential form:
$$ =\frac{1}{\left(1-in\right)\pi}\left[\frac{e^{\pi\left(1-in\right)}-e^{-\pi\left(1-in\right)}}{2}\right]=\frac{1}{\left(1-in\right)\pi}\left[\frac{e^{\pi}\cdot e^{-in}-e^{-\pi}\cdot e^{in}}{2}\right]
 =\frac{e^{-\pi}}{\left(1-in\right)\pi}\left[\frac{e^{2\pi}\cdot\left(\cos\left(n\right)-i\sin\left(n\right)\right)-\left(\cos\left(n\right)-i\sin\left(n\right)\right)}{2}\right]
 =\frac{e^{-\pi}}{2\left(1-in\right)\pi}\left(e^{2\pi}-1\right)\cdot\left(\cos\left(n\right)-i\sin\left(n\right)\right)=\frac{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{e^{-in}}{1-in}$$
IDK what else I can do, and I don't think that's the answer (I don't have an answer)

You're almost there. Using that $e^{\mp \pi i n} = (-1)^n$ to simplify gives
\begin{align}
c_n
&= \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^x e^{-i n x} \,dx \\
&= \frac1{2\pi} \left.\frac{1}{1 - i n} e^{(1 - i n) x}\right\vert_{-\pi}^\pi \\
&= \frac1{2\pi} \frac{1 + i n}{1 + n^2} (-1)^n (e^\pi - e^{-\pi}) \\
&= \boxed{(-1)^n \frac{(1 + i n)}{(1 + n^2)} \frac{\sinh \pi}\pi} .
\end{align}
Figure. Plot of $\color{#7f0000}{e^x}$ and its truncated Fourier series, \begin{split}\color{#00007f}{\sum_{|n| \leq N} c_n e^{i n x} = \sum_{|n| \leq N} (-1)^n \frac{(1 + i n)}{(1 + n^2)} \frac{\sinh \pi}\pi e^{i n x} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi} \left(1 + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{1 + n^2} (\cos n x - n \sin n x) \right)}\end{split} (shown with $N = 8$).

Cf. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinhcFunction.html

thanks, your explanation was really clear and helpful.

You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

The first part is correct: $c_n=i \frac{\sin(\pi(1-in))}{\pi(1-in)}=i \text{ sinc}(\pi(1-in))$.
In the second part you have a sign error when you go from $e^{in}$ to $(\cos(n)-i \sin(n))$ and you also forgot to distribute the $\pi$, so it should be $(\cos(\pi n)+i \sin(\pi n))$.
When you fix this error, you can rewrite it with hyperbolic and normal trigonometric functions (you could also arrive at this with the formula for the sine of the sum of two arguments).
In that case you get $c_n=\frac{\sinh(\pi n)}{\pi(i+n)}$.

thanks! i managed to solve it now
